# Should `db:clear` command truncate Passport tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In testing I used the `db:clear` command in an effort to truncate my data.  The command description states:

> Clear all tables except for Passport and Laravel tables

However when I ran it, the following was output, and the tables were truncated:

```
Truncated oauth_access_tokens
Truncated oauth_auth_codes
Truncated oauth_personal_access_clients
Truncated oauth_refresh_tokens
```

Based on the command description, I was not expecting these tables to be truncated.  Is this expectation incorrect?  I attempted to find the command in question to see if this was intended functionality, but could not find it in the Laravel source.

Laravel version 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation into the data after clearing the DB, this appears to have only touched some of the Passport tables.  I was not expecting to see any Passport tables in the command output based on the command description, but it seems it does truncate Passport tables that have non-reusable data like access tokens and auth codes.  It does keep data for things like clients though.

It is still unclear to me where the command is located, but that was a secondary concern.

Comment: There is no such command in laravel framework. It should be from one of your installed packages.